# Are some infinite fractions in one counting system non-infinite in another?

Tags: fractions, binary

I'm curious whether some infinite periodic fractions in one counting system (e.g. decimal - 10/3 = 3.33333...) turn out to be non-infinite in another system and vice - versa.

Please excuse me if my terminology is not 100% accurate.

Comment: Traditionally, "repeating" and "terminating" are used rather than non-infinite and infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

$10_{10}/3 = 3 \frac{1}{3} = 10.1_3$, for instance.

Basically, if the denominator divides a sufficiently high power of the base, then the radix representation will terminate.

For example, $128|10^7$, so $\frac{1}{128_{10}}$ terminates in base 10 but continues forever in base 3.

Comment: Thanks for the posts k_g. Could you please elaborate on the last sentence. What do you mean with the first expression; is that 128 divided by 10 to the power of 7 (10000000)?

Comment: $\frac{10^7}{128}$ is an integer. That means that $\frac{1}{128}$ = some integer $\times 10^{-7}$, which means that it should terminate in 7 digits at maximum.

Comment: Great stuff dude. Just a couple more questions - how do you know that there is no "n" such that (128^n)/3 = int? Can "n" be a non-integer?

Comment: n has to be an integer since it represents the number of digits. Also, it isn't $3|128^n$, in this example, you'd have to find a $3^n |128 \implies 3^n = 128k \implies 3^n = 2^7k$, which is impossible because of factoring.

Comment: if it wasn't clear, in general what you do is factor the base, then check to see if your denominator is only a product of those factors. So 1/28 works in base 14 (2*7), but not in base 16 ($2^4$)

Comment: It was clear, I just made a silly error. Thanks!
 
Can you now explain why there are no "n" and "k" such that 3^n = 27*k? :)

Comment: I am assuming that you mean 2^7. Basically, 3^n contains only the factor 3, while 2^7 includes the factors 2. So k would have to be Power of three/Power of two greater than 7, which cannot be an integer (you can't cancel anything)